# m3u file collector

Tags: python, beginner, file-system, console

I'm new to Python and wrote this code for collecting all files in an m3u (playlist) file and copying them into a directory.

```
import shutil
import os
import sys

args = sys.argv

#check for m3u file
if len(args) > 1 :   
    m3ufile = args[1]
else :
    print "m3u file must be set"
    sys.exit()

#check for destination arg
try :
    dest = args[2]
except IndexError :
    dest = '.'

#check for destination exists
if os.path.exists(dest) != True and dest != '.' :
    os.makedirs(dest)

files = []     
with open(m3ufile) as f:
    for t in f :
        if t[0] != '#' and t not in ['\n','\r\n'] :
            t = t.strip()
            if t :
                files.append(t)

x = 0
fp = len(files)

while x < fp :
    print(chr(27) + "[2J")
    print str(x + 1) + ' of ' + str(fp) + ' collected!!'
    if os.path.exists(files[x]) : 
        shutil.copy( files[x] , dest)
    x = x + 1

print "all files collected in " + dest + " directory.enjoy!"
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I recommend that you add more to your post. What are you looking for in a review? And, possibly, what is your code doing to accomplish the task you describe?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7 or 3.x? It's relevant to one of the suggestions given in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Command-line handling

Fatal errors should be reported on `sys.stderr` and cause a non-zero exit status.

[Don't check for `os.path.exists(dest)`](//stackoverflow.com/q/273192/1157100), because:

- Existence doesn't actually guarantee that it is a directory rather than a regular file.
- `os.makedirs(dest)` will perform that check anyway.
- Even if you `os.path.exists()` finds a directory, there is a slim chance that it might get deleted in a race condition.

If you want to catch `IndexError` instead of checking for the length of `sys.argv`, then I suggest that you do so consistently for both arguments:

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    m3ufile = sys.argv.pop(1)
except IndexError:
    print("No m3u file given", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    dest = sys.argv.pop(1)
except IndexError:
    dest = '.'
else:
    os.makedirs(dest)
```

### File input

`t` is a funny variable name.  How about `line` instead?

`t not in ['\n','\r\n']` is superfluous, since `if t` performs the same check.

```
files = []
with open(m3ufile) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line and line[0] != '#':
            files.append(line)
```

(This isn't exactly equivalent to your original code, in that it also treats `#` as a comment even if it is preceded by whitespace.  I consider that to be an improvement.)

### Copying

The `Esc[2J` VT100 escape code deserves a comment.  Also consider using [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) for clarity and generality.

You shouldn't declare that something is done until it's done, especially if there's a chance that you might not do it at all.  In fact, I would expect that a missing file would be considered an error.

I suggest using [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to track the progress.

```
from itertools import count

progress, goal = count(1), len(files)
skipped = []
for path in files:
    # Esc [2J is the VT100 sequence to erase the screen and move the cursor to
    # the beginning of the line
    if os.path.exists(path):
        shutil.copy(path, dest)
        print("\x1b[2J{0} of {1} collected!!".format(next(progress), goal))
    else:
        skipped.append(path)

if skipped:
    print("Missing files:", file=sys.stderr)
    for path in skipped:
        print(path, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(2)
else:
    print("All files collected in {0} directory.  Enjoy!".format(dest))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have another question.  if m3u file not found I will get an error. how can I handle it ?

Comment: *"makedirs will perform that check anyway"* [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) says the opposite, it says an error will be raised if you try and make an existing folder. Though on Python 3 it seems that they added an optional parameter where you can tell it to ignore such errors.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `os.path.exists(dest) != True`, just use `if not os.path.exists(dest)`. In general, test booleans simply like this instead of using equivalence for them.

`x = x + 1` can be rewritten much easier as `x += 1`.

You should also use `str.startswith` instead of indexing the zero value, as it's more readable.

```
t.startswith('#')
```

And you should use string formatting. It makes it easier to insert values into strings, like this:

```
str(x + 1) + ' of ' + str(fp) + ' collected!!'
```

can be turned into this:

```
'{} of {} collected!!'.format(x + 1, fp)
```

It automatically converts the parameters to strings, and then places them where the `{}` are in your string literal.